# TFS Build : How to identify previous successful build number?

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines

In TFS Build pipeline: How to identify previous successful build number?

Comment: Please check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and describe a bit more your problem

Comment: Do you want to get a previous successful build from a build definition or a build agent?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check previous successful build from a build definition, you could check **History** of a build definition.

If you want to check previous successful build from a build agent, you could check **Requests** for this agent in Agent Queue or Agent Pool.

Also, [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds) could get a list of successful build easily. The API is similar to the format below:

```
GET https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0&resultFilter=succeeded
```